# Creating child process without getting memory rights to parent

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, kernel-module, win32-process

I'm trying create child process without getting `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` rights to parent that way:

Using kernel driver with `ObRegisterCallbacks` I remove `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` access when parent try to get handle of starting child process:

1. In parent process I use `CreateProcess` function to start child process, but it fails with error that I'm not having rights.
2. I'm also tried to use `RtlCreateUserProcess` and this succeed, but as you may know process now running without subsystem and it doesn't work properly.

So for all these reasons I have three questions:

1. Maybe it is possible to use some `ntdll.dll` function which will create process properly without writing in child memory?
2. Maybe it is possible to hook some `Nt` functions and elevate all write requests during process creating to my kernel driver? If yes, what functions do I need to hook? I hooked `NtWriteVirtualMemory`, but `ntdll.dll` checks access right before call it
3. Maybe it is possible to finish proper process creating myself after using `RtlCreateUserProcess`? If yes, what function I need to use?

Not getting memory access to parent process is very critical for me as I need to protect child memory from all UserMode tricks, `ObRegisterCallback` is good for it, but parent process (launcher) is a big hole.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041629/block-openprocess-and-writeprocessmemory-for-my-game-to-prevent-cheating

Comment: Hans Passant, the solution in this topic you provided is not good and don't answers my quesions. jww uses his ProtectProcess function but it is not problem to write in memory before you use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe it is possible to hook some `Nt` functions and elevate all write requests during process creating to my kernel driver? If yes, what
>   functions do I need to hook? I hooked `NtWriteVirtualMemory`, but ntdll.dll
>   checks access right before call it

Yes, that's all you need to do. Hook `NtWriteVirtualMemory`, which is called from `CreateProcessInternalW`. This avoids `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` and in this case all will work.

> ntdll.dll checks access right before call it

You're mistaken - nothing like this happens.

In `ObjectPreCallback` are you checking that the request is from your parent process and removing `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` only if it is? During process creation `CsrClientCallServer` is called, and as result csrss.exe also opens a child process. Are you sure that you're not removing `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` here?

Of course its also possible use `RtlCreateUserProcess`, but in this case you will be need connect to csrss by yourself and use undocumented and probably unstable interfaces. I think this is not the best way, but it is possible.

And no there isn't another ntdll API for creating processes with csrss connected.

Comment: Thanks! I really was mistaken, after some debug i discover that wow64 `ntdll.dll` use `NtWow64WriteVirtualMemory64` before `NtWriteVirtualMemory`

Comment: yes, you right - need hook NtWow64WriteVirtualMemory64 also, in wow64, i forget about this

Comment: Hi, do you know hether it possible to install win32 subsystem myself?

Comment: @Kracken - what you mean under " install win32 subsystem" ?

Comment: when parent process create child process, parent only do with memory is just write ShimData and then paste pointer to Peb->ShimData, is it possible to create shimdata myself in driver?

Comment: at first - this depended from OS version - say on xp - parent process write environment block to memory of child process, when beginning from win7 (or vista) this is already done in kernel. about  Peb->ShimData - this is optional, not mandatory parameter. really can be 0 and all will be work fine. when not  0 - here point to WCHAR string - name of shimeng.dll (or it analog) - system use LoadLibrary(Peb->ShimData) and then setup shim engine. but how i say this is optional

Comment: i quick looked - early ShimData was simply pointer to unicode string, where was dll name, which must be loaded as shim. but begin from win8 this is already not string, but some struct - look for SbUpdateSwitchContextBasedOnDll. - so this is very depended from windows version. however 0 for ShimData - is legal value

Comment: Thanks! When i set 0 to Peb->ShimData - all is fine on vista-7, but on windows 8+ there are many problems, win32 subsystem can't load. And i'm trying to paste something to Peb->Shimdata from kernel thus child process work fine

Comment: the reason to do this is to avoid any parent process writings to child process memory, without lifting requests to kernel driver. All works fine on Vista-7, but on 8 there are problems

Comment: is it possible to just paste zeros on this struct?

Comment: need have 0 in pShimData pointer in PEB. so even nothing need paste. it 0 by default. so and not touch it

Comment: it is very strange because on Windows 8.1 x64 for example, parent process writes only 2 times, first time he allocates memory and write here some data(many zeros, binary name and some random bytes), the second he writes to Peb+0x2D8(ShimData) pointer to allocated memory i mentioned above. If i will return STATUS_SUCCESS on this writings but really don't write anything - process run in native mode

Comment: i just check exactly on  Windows 8.1 x64  - under debugger skip real ZwWriteVirtualmemory - child process created and worked well

Comment: yes, but it run in native mode. If i will inject dll(with CreateRemoteThread) and call for example GetVersionInfo - it returns wrond value. Many strange things like that

Comment: what you mean "run in native mode" ? yes shimeng.dll do many api hooks for "fix" some result, but this need not for all apps. read about shimeng and how it worked

Comment: but for apps with DirectX it is needed?

Comment: i think here task not in DirectX or any another, but how it ready for work on win 8.1/ win 10. are need compatibility shim for this app. for some app need, for some - no

Comment: @Kracken look for this - http://i.imgur.com/eAx2arl.png - shimdata is used for "select implematation" of many win32 api (on picture for CreateFile), however 0 pointer is also legal. than already all depended from concrete app

Comment: Thanks for answer! As i understand i could create myself that struct pointed in Peb->2D8 but how to do it? Maybe i could use some undocumented function?

Comment: no any exported API for create this struct. and this is very version depended. however how i say - pointer to it can be 0. for windows by self this is not problem, why this is problem for some legacy app - dont know